# MAMP PRO with SSL and Wordpress - Cannot access interior pages of site

Tags: virtual-hosts

I'M using MAMP Pro and I've set up a unique host using the built in SSL certificate in MAMP. I've run a find an replace in the original DB so that the new URL matches the local URL, ex: https://xyzsitename:8890/ which connects just fine, I can see the homepage.

But when I try to access any other pages of the site like https://xyzsitename:8890/about-us/ I get an error saying "The requested URL /about-us/ was not found on this server."

I've used MAMP for a long time and never had this issue, maybe this is a MAMP Pro setting or an issue with using the SSL but I've read through all the docs and it seems like I have it set up correctly. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: As you sure that mod_rewrite is active

Comment: I'm using the default wordpress .htaccess file:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: how is that answers my question? check you server configuration

Comment: Did you re-save your permalink settings after changing urls to https in your database?